# Google Analytics Core Reporting API - Result is always limited to one million rows

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Core Reporting API to get some reports from GA and save them locally to DB. I have a website that has quite a lot of data since 2007 and I try to create some query that returns huge amount of rows, for example:

start-date = 2007-01-01

end-date = 2015-12-31

metrics = ga:pageviews

dimensions = ga:pagePath, ga:date, ga:hour, ga:cityId

sort = -ga:date

samplingLevel = HIGHER_PRECISION

Then the script in automatically pages through results using max allowed limit (max-results = 10000). The problem is that total number of results is one million exactly.

When I change end-date to 2014-12-31, the result still has one million rows. As I use dimension ga:date, there must be more rows in the first example, right? The first date in both result sets is the same (starting date). The date in last row in both results is equal to ending date. So it seems, both result sets were not cut/limited/reduced (can't figure right word in english).

Also I didn't find anything about one million limit in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas).

Comment: did you check the result does it say the results are sampled?   Remember even set with samplingLevel = HIGHER_PRECISION wont prevent sampling.

Comment: I tried it now in Query Explorer. It says "Contains sampled data:Yes". When I try to set date range to only one year, the result has cca 750k rows and it says "Contains sampled data:No".

Comment: Side note.   That request is insane.   8 years every page every day and ever hour by every city.   I would sample you to :)

Comment: then loop it one year at a time if you must run your insane request.  Note: I have a couple of insane requests that I am forced to loop over every three days to prevent sampling.

Comment: My goal is to make as few requests as possible because of quotas/limits. I have to make tens of reports like the mentioned one. And it has to work with any website. Some website can have so many different cities/countries that even if I set range to half a year, it can be > 1M rows.

Comment: remember the data wont change so once you extract the data for 2007 you wont have to do it again.  If you want to avoid sampling you need to either loop it over each year or cut down on the crazy query. I would say remove hour for starters.

Comment: OK, so it seems like the only problem is sampling (I haven't read much about that). So result set with less than 1M rows is sampled, otherwise not and I have to limit my queries (e.g. using smaller date range).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned it sounds like this is a sampling issue. There isn't any 1 million row limit. Here is a [solution that uses Python and the Google Analytics reporting API](http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/) to break your large data range into multiple smaller date ranges and queries to avoid sampling. In the example over 1 million rows of data are pulled.

Comment: Hey, I've seen your solution implemented and it works for the most part, but I believe I'm running into an issue where a single day has more than 1 million rows in my GA pull do to log level data. Any ideas under that circumstance?

Comment: Yes, I'm facing the same issue more than 1 million rows in a single day.

Comment: @JitendraTiwari can you share an example request you're making where you are seeing this issue? It would be helpful to see the date range, dimensions and whether or not you're spanning all sessions or a subset of them using segmenting.

Comment: @JonathonOgden please see the example response in the below post. I know the total records are more than 1.5M but return only 1M

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathon Ogden

Please see the example request below:

{"reportRequests":[{"viewId":"ga:XXXXXXX","dateRanges":[{"startDate":"2020-06-21","endDate":"2020-06-23"}],"dimensions":[{"name":"ga:Hour"},{"name":"ga:ChannelGrouping"},{"name":"ga:SocialNetwork"},{"name":"ga:deviceCategory"},{"name":"ga:Latitude"},{"name":"ga:Longitude"},{"name":"ga:PagePath"},{"name":"ga:Campaign"},{"name":"ga:PageDepth"}],"metrics":[{"expression":"ga:Sessions"},{"expression":"ga:sessionDuration"},{"expression":"ga:pageviews"},{"expression":"ga:Users"},{"expression":"ga:Bounces"},{"expression":"ga:NewUsers"},{"expression":"ga:OrganicSearches"},{"expression":"ga:Entrances"},{"expression":"ga:UniquePageViews"},{"expression":"ga:Exits"}]}],"useResourceQuotas":true}